# How to create movie from images *with transitions between images*

Tags: ios

There seem to be lots of iOS developers who want to create a movie from a set of images, but I would like to include a transition between the images -- just a quick opacity ramp from one image to the next.

I've been googling and studying the docs, and can't see how this can be done with AVAssetWriter. It looks like I need to use AVMutableComposition to get the transitions.

Question: Is this correct? Or am I missing something with AVAssetWriter?

TIA: John

Comment: Well, after a few days working on this, I think I need a combination of AVAssetWriter and AVComposition. I don't think it's possible to create an AVAsset directly from an image. An AVAsset, by definition, is a "timed audiovisual media such as videos and sounds". However, I think I can create a short video from an image using AVAssetWriter, and then use this video to create an AVAsset. That's my current plan, anyway. No one seems to have much experience with this sort of stuff.

Comment: could you added transition between the images, could you please share detail answer with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried, but how about Core Animation to do the transition (or any kind of animation)? You setup the animation, move the timeline, grab a "screenshot" of the animation and write it on the movie. Repeat it until the animation is completed.

Comment: H'mmm. That's an interesting idea. I'll do some reading on it.

Comment: I'm writing an application to do it right now, I'll update this question if it works (and probably publish the sample code) :)

Comment: Cool. I've got to find some way to do this, so I'll do the same.

Comment: @John could you please share sample code , I am also facing same problem in my project

Comment: @JaywantKhedkar, sorry man... That was a long time ago! I did eventually solve the problem, but I can't remember how I did it.